# TortoiseSVN SendRpt.exe can't be found

Tags: tortoisesvn

I've been having issues with TortoiseSVN 1.9 and IntelliJ 14 for a while, which disappeared after downgrading Tortoise to 1.8 (thank you, Lazy Badger for the answer).

Now whenever I right-click a folder I get a popup titled "CrashHandler initialization error" and the following message: "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\SendRpt.exe not found". It's a native crash handler of Tortoise, but its exe is not in the bin folder for some reason.

Tortoise works, it's not a blocking issue, but a very annoying one.

Wanted to attach a screenshot, but don't have enough reputation. :/

Answer (score 47):

@Olga VDB's answer works. But for anyone who doesn't want to reboot their PC - just killing/re-starting `Explorer.exe` works too.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes, as it's much faster than the reboot and works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 34):

Actually just needed to reboot PC. Not deleting the question, maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features. Click on TortoiseSVN and do "Repair". Its will get it resolved this issue.

Comment: It didn't helped me either, but after uninstalling it, it worked.

Comment: This one fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Control Panel > Programs, Uninstall the prior version of Tortoise SVN.

Reboot.

Go to the folder where SVN had been installed and, if it is not already empty, manually delete any remaining files. ( If the DLL files in the bin folder are locked and you cannot delete them, rename them individually, e.g. from .DLL to .DLL.off. After the next reboot cycle, you will find that the files can be deleted. )

Then install the new version of Tortoise SVN.

Although the above answers seem quicker, if you have already tried them and you are still getting endless crash handler error messages every time you right-click anything in Windows File Explorer, go through this complete cycle to clear up the problem.

This worked for me on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit "1703", going from Tortoise SVN v1.9.5 to v1.9.6.

There is an explanation about the different versions of the Tortoise SVN crash handler [on the Tortoise SVN site](https://tortoisesvn.net/crashhandler.html)